# How to parse a query string in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hello I´m using react router and I need to pass some querystring parameters

tried with

```
<Route path="/result/:type?/?filter=:filter?" exact strict component={Result}/>
```

I was expecting that to catch urls like

```
/result
/result/animals
/result/cars
/result/animals?filter=cats,dogs
/result/cars?filter=sedan,truck
```

what´s the right way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For *url parameters*, like `/animals` and `/cars`, you can use the colon syntax `/:type`

But for *query parameters*, like `?filter=something`, you need to parse the query string.

According to react-router docs:

> React Router does not have any opinions about how your parse URL
>   query
>           strings. Some applications use simple key=value query strings, but
>           others embed arrays and objects in the query string. So it's up to you
>           to parse the search string yourself.
>
> In modern browsers that support
>       
>         [the URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
>       
>       , you can instantiate a `URLSearchParams` object from
>       `location.search` and use that.
>
> In
>       
>         [browsers that do not support the URL API (read: IE)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url)
>       
>       you can use a 3rd party library such as
>       [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string).

For example, in your component you will have `location` as a prop from the parent `Route` (or you can get it from `withRouter`), you can then use `location.search` to parse the query string like this:

```js
function Parent({location}) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  return <Child name={params.get("filter")} />;
}
```

**For more info:**

- [React Router Docs - Query Parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters)
- [Example CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/yq2wz8okxx)

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of React Router offered this functionality but ultimately they decided it was too cumbersome to handle the variation across browsers.

As of the current version (v4), you need to use a library, such as [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

One more option to consider: if you know your target browsers support the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API, you can use that instead.

### Install package:

`yarn add query-string`

### Usage:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the library you don't need to add the query string in the Route:

Here is an example:

```
import React from "react";
import qs from "query-string";

const Home = (props) => {
  console.log(props.location.search);
  const query = qs.parse(props.location.search, {
    ignoreQueryPrefix: true
  });
  console.log(query);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[Edit @ CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-mw9b4)

Comment: This doesn't work. says Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

With react router 6.20 you can use useSearchParams, [docs here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params).

I used it like this, in my case I'm looking for the value of `t` in my code my query string is like this `www.mysite.com?t=some_value`:

```
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const YourComponent = () => {

   const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
   console.log(searchParams.get("t"));
   // logs some_value...

   return (/* Your stuff... */)
}
```