# React: pass a query string into a path

Tags: reactjs, string, parameters, routes

I am trying to apply the answer given in this post
[How to parse a query string in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332230/how-to-parse-a-query-string-in-react-router)

but it's not working.

This is my url:

```
`/api/lexemes?searchTerm=${searchTerm}&optionValue=${optionValue}`
```

First, nothing shows when I run this code:

```
let search = window.location.search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(search);
let foo = params.get('searchTerm');
console.log(foo);
```

nor does this one:

```
let url = this.props.location.search;
let params = queryString.parse(url);
console.log(params);
```

When I do:

```
console.log(this.props);
```

The console shows Location with search= ""

Please note that I am using Class Components, does it work only with functional ones? If you could tell me how to do this with a class component that would be great.

My paths in App.js look like this now:

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
          ...
</Switch>
```

What I would like to have is:

```
<Route exact path="/:search/:option" component={Main} />
```

This is my axios call in Main.js

```
handleSubmit = (searchTerm, optionValue) => {
axios
  .get(`/api/lexemes?searchTerm=${searchTerm}&optionValue=${optionValue}`, {

  })
  .then(
    (res) => {
      if (Array.isArray(res.data) && res.data.length === 0) {
        this.setState({
          noData: 1,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          words: res.data,
          currentScreen: "WordItem",
        });
      }

    },
    (error) => {
      alert("handleSubmit error " + error);
    }
  );
```

};

Comment: Wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC. You can then access the query string in your location prop

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if you want to use

```js
<Route exact path="/:search/:option" component={Main} />
```

This is the code for App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Main } from "./Main";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:search/:option" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

This is the code for component Main:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("location match params", this.props.match.params);
    return <div>Home</div>;
  }
}

export { Main };
```

This is class component and you will have access to params from Main component.

Instead of

```js
let url = this.props.location.search;
let params = queryString.parse(url);
console.log(params);
```

Use `this.props.match.location` to access params from `<Route exact path="/:search/:option" component={Main} />`

Comment: Where do I put  "this.props.match.location" inside App.js or in Main.js? And how will this affect the route Path?

Comment: Inside Main.js. I left you Main.js code in the answer. Now in Main you can access to params. 

As you can see i left console.log to show you the values.
This is the correct flow to access param url in React-router class component

Comment: sorry for the dumb question again: but in Main.js there's only a console.log("location match params", this.props.match.params);
    return <div>Home</div>; I want to understand how logging the params will be passed into the Route in App.js

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand very well. Do you want to know how to receive params in Main? If you want we can use chat to talk about the problem there

Comment: I hope you understand after the chat. I will save code sandbox if you need something else :)

Comment: Yes it's clear now. Thanks for taking the time to explain things